# plugin failed to connect to development mode server at 127.0.0.1

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am using GWT 2.3.0 as a plugin for Eclipse to develop a web based application

Unfortunately, when I try to run my application I get:

```
plugin failed to connect to developer mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997
```

and

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception :java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I have installed the Gwt developer plugin for Google Chrome and every time I run my project it requires me to install this plugin and restart the browser, after which I get the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Maybe Port 9997 is already in use? Did you try 'Automaticall select unused port' in the GWT tap in run configuration? Did you try on external server with noserver option? Could you post the fully stack trace?

Comment: Chrome plugin: Do you have the same problem with firefox?

Answer (score 15):

You can solve this issue by:

1. Right click on your web project -> Run as -> Run configurations.
2. Select 'Server' and 'GWT' tabs respectively and check on 'Automatically select an unused port'
3. Clear Cache from your Chrome browser (do the same on Firefox if you are using Firefox, remember the GWT plugin is not available on the latest Firefox versions, 3-10 I believe).
4. Run and hopefully enjoy.

Comment: This works, I think the issue was with the refreshing. When I do refresh a lot, then Chrome will get this error eventually. But strange thing is that firefox will load up the URL properly. Removing the 9997 worked for a while until I hit some errors when using GWT-RPC.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's an old question but,
I ran into the same problem today.

For some reason (quite unknown to me) deleting the ":9997" from the end of the address fixed it, and the application came up nicely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me too - maybe has something to do with invalid caches being cleared as mentioned by @rdsoze [in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7875469/270662).

Comment: Worked for me. The port numbers on both the url's didn't match. http://127.0.0.1:57229/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: similar here, I had two Chrome instances running different user-profiles, one worked and the other didn't. removing port number fixed it now it works on both...

Answer (score 4):

Look at http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2010/12/debug-google-web-toolkit-applications.html for a step by step instruction on how to set up chrome, particularly the last part on how to setup the plugin using an external web server.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem that you faced : plugin failed to connect to developer mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997 , just clear your browser cache and try once again.

Answer (score 0):

Just happend to me today too, and I've managed to fix it:

It turns out that the set of the GWT modules to be loaded is configureable; by referring to one of the GWT html's from the browser, it appears I was actually trying to connect to a page under a module that has been removed from the run-config's modules list. So, one more thing to do is to verify the list's content:

In eclipse: "Run Configurations" > Web Application > (your app) > GWT tab > Available Modules

In IntelliJ (that's what I've used): Edit Configurations > (select your GWT config) > GWT Modules to load

Answer (score 0):

The GWT Plugin may be need to restarted

First Clear Browser cash
Second : try the following on chrome browser
    -

1. open :  chrome://extensions/
2. Go to : GWT Developer Plugin
3. uncheck the Enabled box
4. check the Enabled box

Open URL again and have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by only clearing the browser cache. I am working with Firefox 15.0.1